# onDelete not being called when deleting a node in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build triggers for a firebase app around following and followers.  Below is a snippet of my cloud code.  I want to increase a counter when a user follows.  For this I use oncreate (for when the user gains their first follower due the structure not existing until this point) and then I use onupdate.  I then use ondelete to decrement the following count when a user unfollows and is removed.

The problem I am having is that .ondelete is not being called and only .onupdate is being called regardless of users being added or removed (which looking back makes sense I guess).  My question is how to write the cloud functions to separate the deletions from the additions.

the database looks something like this

```
user1
  - following
     -user2
       -small amount of user2data
     -user3
       -small amount of user3data
```

And the code:

```
    exports.countFollowersUpdate = functions.database.ref('/{pushId}/followers/')
        .onUpdate(event => {

          console.log("countFollowers")


          event.data.ref.parent.child('followers_count').transaction(function (current_value) {

            return (current_value || 0) + 1;
          });


        });

exports.countFollowersCreate = functions.database.ref('/{pushId}/followers/')
    .onCreate(event => {

      console.log("countFollowers")


      event.data.ref.parent.child('followers_count').transaction(function (current_value) {

        return (current_value || 0) + 1;
      });


    });


exports.countFollowersDelete = functions.database.ref('/{pushId}/followers/')
    .onDelete(event => {

      console.log("countFollowers2")


      event.data.ref.parent.child('followers_count').transaction(function (current_value) {

        if ((current_value - 1) > 0) {
          return (current_value - 1);
        }
        else{
          return 0;
        }
      });
```

Comment: read my question again.  The server doesn't know if it's a follow or unfollow.  It only knows how the data was edited.  The problem is that it can't tell the difference between an update and a delete.  As for your first question it is horrible from an efficiency stand point to count the entire number every transaction.

Comment: Please indicate how the client i adding the data to the database.  Also note that your database structure is unreadable in your question - it requires formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`onDelete` isn't being called because you're listening to the entire `followers` node, so it would only be called when follower counts goes to zero (nothing left). Instead you probably want all of these to be more like:

```
functions.database.ref('/{pushId}/followers/{followerId}').onDelete()
```

It's also unusual that you have a top-level push id. A structure would normally be more like `/users/{pushId}/followers/{followerId}`.